# FreeGLUT or Mesa, which one should I use?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glut, freeglut, mesa

So as the title says, which one would you choose? It would be great if one can also explain the reasons behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FreeGLUT is a simplicistic framework for the creation of small OpenGL demos. Alternatives to FreeGLUT would be SDL, GLFW, or full blown frameworks like Qt.

Mesa is a open source implementation of the OpenGL API, and together with the DRI/DRM project drivers forms a full HW accelerated OpenGL implementation. If you're using Linux and use your GPU with open source drivers, Mesa **is** the OpenGL implementation you use. That's not a choice, that's a fact.

They're completely different things and neither can replace the other.

Comment: Seems like Mesa *does* [provide](ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/glut/) a GLUT implementation, at least for GLX and Win32.

Comment: @genpfault: I wasn't aware of that. But this is called MesaGLUT then.